# How to filter data with aggregation + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need a help to improve my filters, this is the code:

```
import pandas as     pd
from   pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy  as     np
import plotly.express as px
import xlrd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',  600)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',      500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',   900)
pd.set_option('display.width',        1500)
pd.options.display.float_format = '€{:,.0f}'.format

df  = pd.read_excel('5GPPP-Cordis-v05.xlsx', sheet_name="Data")
df.head(2)

    Year    Project Entity  Participation   Country Budget
0   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   UNIVERSIDAD CARLOS III DE MADRID-IMDEA NETWORKS Participant Spain   €384,000
1   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   ROHDE & SCHWARZ GMBH*   Participant Germany €12,000


3. Entities
aggregation = {
               'Projects':     ('Project',      pd.Series.nunique),
               'Coordination': ('Coordinator', 'sum'),
               'Budget':       ('Budget',      'sum')
              }
​
df.groupby(['Country','Entity']).agg(**aggregation).nlargest(60,['Budget', 'Coordination', 'Projects']).reset_index()

    Country Entity  Projects    Coordination    Budget
0   Germany FRAUNHOFER GESELLSCHAFT EV  21  1   €20,650,842
1   Spain   TELEFONICA INVESTIGACION Y DESARROLLO SA*   26  0   €15,182,263
2   France  ORANGE SA*  27  0   €9,517,902
3   Spain   UNIVERSIDAD CARLOS III DE MADRID-IMDEA NETWORKS 16  5   €4,943,855
```

I want to have a similar result that the last filter but just for one entity, i will expect this result:

```
    Country Entity  Projects    Coordination    Budget
1   Spain   TELEFONICA INVESTIGACION Y DESARROLLO SA*   26  0   €15,182,263
```

Another result that i need is the next one:

```
Year    Project                           Entity      Budget
2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G             10        €384.000,000
```

I tried with this code in order to obtain the result:

```
def show_entity (entity_arg, zoom):

    aggregation = {
                   'Projects':     ('Project',      pd.Series.nunique),
                   'Coordination': ('Coordinator', 'sum'),
                   'Budget':       ('Budget',      'sum')
                  }
    df_entity = df.groupby(['Entity']).get_group(entity_arg)
    display(df_entity.groupby(['Entity']).agg(**aggregation).nlargest(zoom,['Budget', 'Coordination', 'Projects']).res
```

This is the result:

```
show_entity ('Universidad', 10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-426a7b2d26a2> in <module>
----> 1 show_entity ('Universidad', 10)

<ipython-input-44-a3046a02ee97> in show_entity(entity_arg, zoom)
      6                    'Budget':       ('Budget',      'sum')
      7                   }
----> 8     df_entity = df.groupby(['Entity']).get_group(entity_arg)
      9     display(df_entity.groupby(['Entity']).agg(**aggregation).nlargest(zoom,['Budget', 'Coordination', 'Projects']).reset_index())

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in get_group(self, name, obj)
    684         inds = self._get_index(name)
    685         if not len(inds):
--> 686             raise KeyError(name)
    687 
    688         return obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=self.axis)

KeyError: 'Universidad'
```

any suggestion would be great.

Comment: And what results do you get with your code?

Comment: I tried with this code in order to obtain the result:

def show_entity (entity_arg, zoom):

    aggregation = {
                   'Projects':     ('Project',      pd.Series.nunique),
                   'Coordination': ('Coordinator', 'sum'),
                   'Budget':       ('Budget',      'sum')
                  }
    df_entity = df.groupby(['Entity']).get_group(entity_arg)
    display(df_entity.groupby(['Entity']).agg(**aggregation).nlargest(zoom,['Budget', 'Coordination', 'Projects']).reset_index())

show_entity ('Universidad', 10)

I have mistakes, help me

Comment: Yeah ok but what did it output?

Comment: this is the output with mistakes:
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-426a7b2d26a2>in<module>
--> 1 show_entity('Universidad',10)
<ipython-input-44-a3046a02ee97> in show_entity(entity_arg,zoom)
6'Budget':('Budget', 'sum')
7 }
--> 8 df_entity=df.groupby(['Entity']).get_group(entity_arg)
9 display(df_entity.groupby(['Entity']).agg(**aggregation).nlargest(zoom,['Budget', 'Coordination','Projects']).reset_index())
684 inds=self._get_index(name)
685 if not len(inds):
--> 686 raise KeyError(name)

Comment: Please put it in your question. Unformated code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: check the update, thanks for being interested in helping me

Comment: the issue is related to 'Universidad' value, ,  your must pass value in capital 'UNIVERSIDAD', according to your post the data frame has entity column with value 'UNIVERSIDAD'. let me know if it works for you or not,   try   show_entity ('UNIVERSIDAD', 10)